# Is it possible to merge a public Github repository (or just a few files from it) into my Azure Devops repro and Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-ad-b2c, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Suppose I have a master branch on GitHub whose updates need to be merged with non-public code on my DevOps instance.

Is it possible to pull externally developed code into a private repo, selectively handle merge conflicts (I only need certain changes), and integrate that with Azure Pipelines?

For a practical example, I want to create a baseline of functional websites based on AzureAD/B2C based on the samples. Since the configuration of those demos needs adjustment in order to work with parameterized depoyment and variables I have saved for each environment (Dev, UAT, Prod).

How would I integrate (only) [this MSFT demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups) into Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Just one confirmation, you said you want to merge part of one github repository. Which method type you are looking for? Completely scripts? Or manually?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I would like to base my production (private Gits) upon the best practices in the samples.  As approaches or guidance is updated, I'd like to merge that (manually) into my project(s).  If dev.azure.com repos allowed me to compare my Program.cs with Azure-Samples, that could ensure not only that I don't lose track of where the source/inspiration code is located, but also can identify better and more stable ways of doing things. Like a merge conflict, but only for auditing / verification by a "manager-type".